# How to get size of the video file from url?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
    VideoView vidView;
    MediaController mediaController;
    LinearLayout btn_download;
    UserService userService;

       userService = ApiUtils.getUserService();
       if(mediaController == null){
          mediaController = new MediaController(ColumnPipeInstallationActivity.this);
          mediaController.setAnchorView(vidView);
       }
    vidView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(url);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);<----on create of activity video will start to play. Is it possible to get size of the file.
    vidView.start();}}
```

onClick of button is it possible to download the file to the device?

Comment: Yes, you can download file to the device. If you check in Google, you will get some sample code or good reference about how to download file from url.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this,

```
public long getFileSizeFromUrl(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
      conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      return conn.getContentLengthLong();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       //Maybe throw the exception, or just stacktrace it. Your call
    } finally {
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.disconnect();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get `content-length` field

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31983132/4224024) if the answer of P Sandesh Baliga does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the length of video on `buttonClick()`

```
 URL url = new URL("URL_OF_YOUR_VIDEO");
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
            Log.w("getContentLength",""+lenghtOfFile);
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Activities.ColumnActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException                                                    try {
            c.connect();   <----here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

Comment: use AsyncTask to call this method

Comment: now using AsyncTask its working.. but ,getContentLength is getting as -1.

Comment: actually video size is in terms of MB